# how does SQL Server actually store russian symbols in char?

Tags: sql-server, encoding

I have a column `NAME`, which is `CHAR(50)`.

It contains the value `'Рулон комбинированный СТЕРИТ 50мм ? 200 м'` 
which integer representation is:

```
'1056,1091,1083,1086,1085,32,1082,1086,1084,1073,1080,1085,1080,1088,1086,1074,1072,1085,1085,1099,1081,32,1057,1058,1045,1056,1048,1058,32,53,48,1084,1084,32,63,32,50,48,48,32,1084'
```

but CHAR implies that it contains 8 bit. How does SQL Server store values like `'1056,1091,1083,1086,1085'` which are UNICODE symbols?

OK, and also `?` symbol is actually `×` (215) (Multiplication Sign)

If SQL Server can represent `'1056'` why it can't represent `'215'`?

Comment: What database are you speaking about ? You can't ask a question related to a data type without specifying the DB

Comment: we use MSSQL DB

Answer (score 1):

What the 255 values in a `char` mean is determined by the database [collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-2017).  For Russia this is typically `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS` (where CI means Case Insentitive and AS means Accent Sensitive.)

There's a good chance this matches [Windows code page 1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251), so `л` is stored as hex EB or decimal 235.  You can verify this with T-SQL:

```
create database d1 collate Cyrillic_General_CI_AS;
use d1
select ascii('л')
-->
235
```

In the Cyrillic code page, decimal 215 means `Ч`, not the multiplication sign.  Because SQL Server can't match the multiplication sign to the Cyrillic code page, it replaces it with a question mark:

```
select ascii('×'), ascii('?')
-->
63      63
```

In the Cyrillic code page, the `char` 8-bit representation of the multiplication sign and the question mark are both decimal 63, the question mark.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a column NAME, which is CHAR(50).
>
> It contains the value 'Рулон комбинированный СТЕРИТ 50мм ? 200 м'
>   which integer representation is:
>
> ```
> '1056,1091,1083,1086,1085,32,1082,1086,1084,1073,1080,1085,1080,1088,1086,1074,1072,1085,1085,1099,1081,32,1057,1058,1045,1056,1048,1058,32,53,48,1084,1084,32,63,32,50,48,48,32,1084'
> ```

Cyted above is wrong.

I make a test within a database with Cyrillic collation and integer representation is different from what you showed us, so or your data type is not char, or your integer representation is wrong, and yes, "but CHAR implies that it contains 8 bit" is correct and here is how you can prove it to youerself:

```
--create table dbo.t (name char(50));
--insert into dbo.t values ('Рулон комбинированный СТЕРИТ 50мм ? 200 м')

select cast (name as binary(50))
from dbo.t;

select substring(cast (name as binary(50)), n, 1) as bin_substr,
       cast(substring(cast (name as binary(50)), n, 1) as int) as int_, 
       char(substring(cast (name as binary(50)), n, 1)) as cyr_char
from dbo.t cross join nums.dbo.nums;
```

Here `dbo.Nums` is an auxiliary table containig integers. I just convert your string from `char` field into `binary`, split it byte per byte and convert into `int` and `char`.

[image]